# loop for tabulation of variables in data frame

Tags: r, loops, frequency

I have a `df` with `n` variables.
I want to loop through a subset of the variables and produce a frequency table.

For example, given `df` below:

```
id a b c d 
1 0 1 0 1 
2 1 0 1 0
3 0 1 0 1
```

I tried to do the following without success:

```
varlist <- c("a", "c")

for (i in varlist){
   print(table(df$i))
               }
```

Comment: `lapply(dat[varliat], table)`

Comment: What about `table(df[varlist])`?

Comment: @UweBlock ; that will give contingency tables of more than one dimension. Looks as if univariate tables are wanted

Comment: @user20650 That's why I didn't post it as an answer but in a comment with a questionmark.  The OP asks "I want to [...] produce _a_ frequency table". (Emphasis by me). That sounds to me like _one_ table. But we can only speculate as the OP unfortunately hasn't disclosed the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(First, your matrix `df` is transformed to a data frame:)

```
df <- setNames(as.data.frame(df), letters[1:4])
```

The `$` does not work with variables. You have to use `[[` instead:

```
for (i in varlist){
  print(table(df[[i]]))
}
```

However, a much easier solution for your problem is `lapply`:

```
lapply(df[varlist], table)
```

---

From the help page of [`Extract`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html):

> The main difference is that `$` does not allow computed indices, whereas `[[` does.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sven, as an addendum, can you explain why $ does not work with variables and [[]] is used instead? Thanks!

Comment: @kquach I added a quote to the answer.