# Create Multiple 2x2 Tables

Tags: r

I need to create multiple 2x2 tables across many variables.

sample data:

```
Month <- c("Jan", "Feb", "March", "April")
Quiz1 <- c("90", "80", "100", "70")
Quiz2 <- c("100", "70", "50", "20")
Quiz3 <- c("60", "35", "26", "80")

df <- data.frame(Month, Quiz1, Quiz2, Quiz3)
```

What I would like to do is get a 2x2 of each of each quiz by month and then save it in a csv so that I can create bar graphs - pie charts, etc in excel and they need to be distributed with non R users. It can be the same CSV or multiple ones, that does not matter. This is how I have been doing it (there are close to 20 quizes) but I know there has got to be a more efficient way.

```
Quiz1 <- table(df$Month, df$Quiz1)
Quiz2 <- table(df$Month, df$Quiz2)
Quiz3 <- table(df$Month, df$Quiz3)

write.csv(Quiz1, "filepath...")
write.csv(Quiz2, "filepath...")
write.csv(Quiz3, "filepath...")
```

I found this answer: [loop for tabulation of variables in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41860939/loop-for-tabulation-of-variables-in-data-frame) and it would work great except it is just for frequency tables and I'm not sure how to adapt it for this scenario and I don't have enough points to leave a comment.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop through the columns except the 'Month' column, then get the `table` of the 'Month' with the looped column.  The output will be a `list` of tables

```
lst <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) table(df$Month, x))
names(lst) <- paste0("Quiz", seq_along(lst))
```

Instead of creating several global variables, a single `list` would serve the purpose.  After the transformations, then use `write.csv` to write into different files

```
lapply(names(lst), function(x) write.csv(lst[[x]], file = paste0(x, ".csv"))
```

Comment: This works on the example data I have posted above but when I try to run this on the larger dataset with all of the quizes I am getting this error: "error in table(df$Month, x): all arguments must have the same length"

Comment: @user7777508  If you have a `data.frame`, it should work fine as the columns have equal length